# get element value by xpath in google chrome addon (javascript)

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I would like to ask some specific question.

I am trying to implement an app using Google Chrome extension, that obtain xpath from another Chrome extension. then finds value of element and do some stuff with it.

I have a listener in chrome addon, that receives JSONs with xpath of html elements that users have pointed on with cursor. For example `/HTML/BODY/DIV[@id='viewport']/DIV[@id='main']/DIV[@id='cnt']/DIV[6]/DIV[@id='rcnt']/DIV[3]/DIV[@id='center_col']/DIV[@id='res']/DIV[@id='search']/DIV[1]/DIV[@id='ires']/OL[@id='rso']/DIV[2]/LI[2]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/SPAN[1]`

I want to obtain the value of that element. So if:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Hello<\div>
<body>
```

and i have `xpath = /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]` for this elements

I want to obtain string "Hello"

I know there is function in javascript to retrieve element:

`var xPathResult = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);`,

But I almost always retrieve null. 
all the code of the is here:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        var index;

        if (msg != null) {
            //   console.log("Received message: " + msg);
            var objJSON = JSON.parse(msg);

            for (index = 0; index < objJSON.length; ++index) {
                var xpath = objJSON[index].xpath;
                var url = objJSON[index].url;

                if (xpath != "Not looking at browser") {

                        var xp = getElementByXPath(xpath); //returns null all the time
                        var value = xp.innerHTML;
                }
            }
        }

    });
});

var getElementByXPath = function (xPath) {
    var xPathResult = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
    return xPathResult.singleNodeValue;
};
```

Can you please help? there are no errors in xpaths - no exception thrown by wrong xpath at runtime and if I inspect the elements in Chrome by xpaths, it also looked ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong `document`. Take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) first.

Your background script lives in a special, invisible page, and `document` refers to that page.

To access the current tab's DOM, you need to inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and execute your code there.